# What is the set of all functions which can be used as a 'convergence factor' for a Fourier Transform?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

At times, I am required to take the Fourier Transform of some function that does not decay quickly enough for the Fourier Transform to converge in the usual sense. For example, $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) e^{-i k x} dx $$ where we must multiply by some "convergence factor" that decays as $\left| x \right| \to \infty$ and then the limit taken so that the "convergence factor" approaches 1. $$\lim_{\eta \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,\eta) \sin(x) e^{-i k x} dx$$ $$\lim_{\eta \to 0} f(x, \eta) = 1$$
The 'magical' part of this procedure is that it seems to not depend on which function $f(x, \eta)$ we choose, so long as it fulfills the above properties.

Question: What assumptions do we need to make about $f(x, \eta)$ to be sure that: (1) The Fourier Transform of some smooth function $g(x)$ that does not grow too quickly as $\left|x\right| \to \infty$ (my guess is that $g(x)$ must grower slower than exponentially) exists and (2) that this transform is independent of our choice of $f(x, \eta)$?

I am trained in physics rather than mathematics, so my understanding of what is rigorously going on here is limited. My basic belief is that this procedure lives in a space larger than the usual elementary functions and includes some distributions. From browsing Wolfram MathWorld it seems like $f(x, \eta)$ being a Schwartz Function with the appropriate limit for $\eta$ is a sufficient condition, but is it necessary?

Comment: Schwartz functions are often used, as are bump functions. Schwartz functions are a bit nicer with regards to the Fourier transform because this space of functions is invariant under the Fourier transform.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but what you're proposing looks very strange. Let's take $f(x, \eta) = g(\eta x)$ where $g$ is a Gaussian function. Are you saying that limit of integral exists and you interpret that as value of the Fourier transform of $\sin x$ at $k$? Why not just talk about the Fourier transform of $\sin x$ as a tempered distribution?

Comment: @Michael If I am understanding you correctly, then your example is to do something like defining the Fourier transform of $\sin(x)$ as $\lim_{\eta \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(x) e^{-\eta^2 x^2} e^{- I k x} dx$. If so, that is exactly what I am proposing. I have seen the words 'tempered distribution' before but I have no idea what they mean.

Comment: @Michael I should also mention that this is common practice in science and engineering courses, so I assumed it was somehow natural and not strange.

Comment: I see, never mind. Not sure if your formula can be made rigorous but it makes sense. To kinda jive with the proper definition, you have to take Schwartz functions whose inverse Fourier transform goes to the Delta function.

Comment: A tempered distribution $S$ is a continuous linear functional on the Schwartz space. The Fourier transform of such an $S$ is defined as the dual of the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ on the Schwartz space: for any Schwartz function $\psi$,

$$
(\mathcal{F}S)(\psi) = S (\mathcal{F}(\psi)).
$$

Take $S = \sin x$. Then very informally, one might ask what is the "value of $\mathcal{F}S$ at a point $k$." To approximate this, one might pick $\psi$ to be "close" to the delta function at $k$. But then $\mathcal{F}(\psi)$ would look like $g(k) e^{ik}$ where $g$ satisfies your condition on decay, etc.

Comment: @Michael Thank you, your comments are quite helpful. I just now noticed that the functions that I commonly use as 'convergence factors' do indeed have inverse Fourier transforms that are the delta function. I almost understand what you wrote about tempered distributions, but I'm clearly lacking some foundation (I don't understand dual of the Fourier Transform or your notation). Could you recommend a reference to me? I don't want to waste your time with trivialities like notation.

Comment: Try Terrence Tao's website. He posts lecture notes on line, in particular those for his analysis class. Can't go wrong with Tao.

Comment: @Michael One more question. Suppose that we do define the Fourier transform of sine in the way that you describe. How do we then compute it??

Comment: Well, if I put on a pure math person's hat, I probably wouldn't see the need for any further "computation". It's a precise definition, it allows you to prove the theorems you want to prove.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10271/discussion-between-kevin-driscoll-and-michael)